# Addres space in windows

Tags: windows, operating-system, virtual-address-space, address-space

If in hard disk there is no free space, what do system when i run application? Where's creating paging file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pagefile location is configured in your system settings. On win7 you can find it here:

- Right click on your "Computer" icon and select properties.
- Click on the "Advanced" tab
- Click the "Settings..." button under "Performance".
- Click on the "Advanced" tab
- Click on the "Change" button under "Virtual Memory"

A large chunk of the paging file will be pre-allocated on the specified drive. But if Windows needs to increase the pagefile and there is not enough room to do so, then the application is told there is no more memory (if it is already running, or it will fail to load if you are just starting it up).

Edit: Responding to the comment about page size vs total virtual memory.

When setting the value for the pagefile size, that value is independent of how much memory you have. They are confusing things because of the terminology used in the dialog, because even though the title of the window is "Virtual Memory" you are only setting the size-on-disk.

So if you set that to 4GB and you have 2GB of RAM, then the size-on-disk is 4GB, but the OS will effectively have 6GB of virtual memory to utilize.

Comment: Can i ask one question too? If i set virtual memory for example 4 gb, my paging file will be 6gb? (because my RAM is 2 gb)